# Watchguard M400 Tagging VLAN

Tags: vlan, watchguard, firebox

I have a problem with WatchGuard Firebox M400.

I put interface 2 into VLAN mode.
I created earlier few VLANs like: 10, 20, 30, 40, 110 and 199.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/UAJncwK.jpg]

When im puting those VLANs in that interface, i checked them all as TAGGED, then when I'm connecting a PC into that WG interface it's not working. I can only ping my default gateway but nothing more.

When i check one as untagged, that one particular VLAN is working, but the other ones (TAGGED) are not.

I need all VLANs in one interface, do you have any idea what is going on?

//Of course I'm NATing those VLANs via dynamic NAT

Best Regards, Kai

Comment: *do you have any idea what is going on?* - that sounds like it's working correctly. What would you expect to happen if you plugged a PC into a socket with several tagged VLANs? Did you configured VLAN interfaces on the PC?

Comment: to be honest, I just restarted the whole watchguard 2 times and it works fine :)